# mkv issue in firefox

Tags: firefox, mkv

I've been searching for this a lot, and I think it is not possible but for being sure:
I have some MKV video files which I want to put them on my website. The problem is you can't
play them in firefox and it only works in chrome browser. I'm using html5 player(js player).

```
<video id="example_video_2" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="800" height="600" poster="<?php echo $teacher_pic ;?>"  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>  <source src='<?php echo $video_url;?>' type='video/mp4' /> </video>

<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "video/video-js/video-js.swf"
</script>
```

I also tried "[Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody)" player but it didn't help. 
So , is it related to player or not ? is it basically possible to play my videos in firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, could this link help you - http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch07.html
If not, maybe you could try adding a type `type="video/x-matroska"` and the explanation is here: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/948571